# Algolia autocomplete issue

Tags: autocomplete, algolia

I have the following search code:

```
        autocomplete('#search-input', {hint: false, autoselect: true}, [
        {
            source: autocomplete.sources.hits(contacts, { hitsPerPage: 3 }),
            displayKey: 'CustomerName',
            templates: {
                header: '<div class="leftMargin5"><b>Contacts</b></div>',
                suggestion: function(hit) {
                    return templateContact.render(hit);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            source: autocomplete.sources.hits(products, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
            displayKey: 'ProductDescription',
            templates: {
                header: '<div class="leftMargin5"><b><Products</b></div>',
                suggestion: function(hit) {
                    return templateProduct.render(hit);
                }
            }
        }

    ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function (event, suggestion, dataset) {
        //DoSomething
    }).on('autocomplete:autocompleted', function (event, suggestion, dataset) {
        //DoSomething
    });
```

My problem is that when I start typing in the search box, the top element is selected and the text in the search box is set to this match. I am unable to keep typing or deleting the text in the search box. Typing or deleting simply keeps selecting the original match.

I am trying to make the first hit highlighted to select it on enter, but I want to be able to keep typing or select another item if the top one is not the one I am looking for.

If I remove the option autoselect: true, the search box works, but of course without the autoselect feature.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle ? This would help us a lot helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg indeed, that's a bug between `autoselect` & the `displayKey` options. You can remove the `displayKey` to work-around the issue and you should open an issue on the [official repository](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js).

**UPDATE**: this has been fixed since `0.21.6`.